# Can't pass multi integers at the same time in intent

Tags: android, android-intent

So I want to pass the data between the activities,so I've make that there's 3 separate integers should be send to the second activity,but i don't know why,the emulator keeps adding all of them. Basically,I making an app, at case of my course - i need to create an app that keeping score,in my case,app would keep the score,number of fouls,and number of corners during the football match. To set the data,we are clicking in special button (press score to increment score etc.) when we want to go to the second activity and see the detailed statistics we should see like 3 goals,6 fouls,and like 2 corners for team "A" during the match,but when i clicking in buttons (suppose that is 1 time for goal,2 times for fouls,and 3 times for corner the app should be like 1 goal,2 fouls,3 corner's but it keep adding all of integers,and it's like 6 goals,6 fouls,6 corners. What can be wrong?

Count activity (here program storage the value of integers)

```
public class CountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public int team_a_score;
public int team_a_foul;
public int team_a_corner;

public int team_b_score;
public int team_b_foul;
public int team_b_corner;

private Button goToDetailedStats;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_count);

goToDetailedStats = (Button) findViewById(R.id.go_to_stats);
goToDetailedStats.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        openDetailedScore();
    }
});

}

private void openDetailedScore() {
Intent intent = new Intent(this,DeatiledScoreActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("",team_a_score);
intent.putExtra("",team_a_foul);
intent.putExtra("",team_a_corner);
startActivity(intent);
}

public void resetScore(View view) {
team_a_score = 0;
display_a_score(team_a_score);

team_b_score = 0;
display_b_score(team_b_score);
}

private void display_a_score (int a_score){
TextView team_a_score_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score_tv);
team_a_score_tv.setText(String.valueOf(a_score));
}
private void display_b_score (int b_score){
TextView team_b_score_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_b_score_tv);
team_b_score_tv.setText(String.valueOf(b_score));
}

public void increment_a_score(View view) {
team_a_score = team_a_score+1;
display_a_score(team_a_score);
}

public void increment_a_foul(View view) {
team_a_foul = team_a_foul+1;
}

public void increment_a_corner(View view) {
team_a_corner = team_a_corner+1;
}

public void increment_b_score(View view) {
team_b_score = team_b_score+1;
display_b_score(team_b_score);
}

public void increment_b_foul(View view) {
team_b_foul = team_b_foul+1;
}

public void increment_b_corner(View view) {
team_b_corner = team_b_corner+1;
}
}
```

Detailed activity have to receive data that we send as intent from Counting activity.

```
public class DeatiledScoreActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_deatiled_score);

int team_a_score_detail_int = 0;
int team_a_foul_detail_int = 0;
int team_a_corner_detail_int = 0;

int team_b_score_detail_int = 0;
int team_b_foul_detail_int = 0;
int team_b_corner_detail_int = 0;

Intent goal_intent = getIntent();
int goal = goal_intent.getIntExtra("", team_a_score_detail_int);
display_a_goal(goal);

Intent foul_intent = getIntent();
int foul = foul_intent.getIntExtra("", team_a_foul_detail_int);
display_a_foul(foul);

Intent corner_intent = getIntent();
int corner = corner_intent.getIntExtra("", team_a_corner_detail_int);
display_a_corner(corner);

}

public void display_a_goal(int score) {
TextView a_score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_goal_detail);
a_score.setText(String.valueOf(score));
}

public void display_a_foul(int foul){
TextView a_foul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_foul_detail);
a_foul.setText(String.valueOf(foul));
```

Answer (score 0):

They cannot have the same key:

```
intent.putExtra("",team_a_score);
intent.putExtra("",team_a_foul);
intent.putExtra("",team_a_corner);
```

So in order to make it work set:

```
intent.putExtra("some",team_a_score);
intent.putExtra("some2",team_a_foul);
intent.putExtra("some4",team_a_corner);
```

[Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) `putExtra` method accepts two arguments key - value.